# Is there any way to change ::after style in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I change ::after in JavaScript?

I want when I hovered on it change the `::after` property `width`.

```js
var li_a = document.getElementsByClassName('effect-underline');
console.log(li_a);
var li_a_width;
var n;

for (n = 0; n < li_a.length; n++) {


    li_a[n].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

        li_a_width = this.offsetWidth;
        this.style.width = li_a_width;
        console.log(li_a_width);
    })
}
```

```css
.effect-underline::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #303F9F;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
    transform: scale(0, 1);
}

.effect-underline:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="effect-underline"><a href="#">Home </a></li>
     <li class="effect-underline"><a href="#">About </a></li>
     <li class="effect-underline"><a href="#">Resume </a></li>
     <li class="effect-underline"><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
```

Please help me to change width property in after by JavaScript.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Comment: What do you need the js for? It does work on my end.

Comment: _"Is there any way to change `::after` style in JavaScript?"_ Yes, you can attach the `::after` pseudo-element styles to a `class` in your CSS and then toggle the `class` using javascript.

Comment: @Ava  Because I want to set the element width dynamical

Comment: @Rounin could I get width dynamic?

Comment: Idk why you need a dynamic width for, you could just set the width from css only.